# Questions don't show up after refresh

Tags: discussion, support

I have observed this problem quite a lot since last couple of months, and I am not sure if I am the only one having this issue.

When I keep the SO website idle and there appears some bar which says "***x new questions***"

I click on it and I am able to view those questions.

But sometimes if I do a refresh, those questions won't show up until I keep doing a refresh for about 2-3 minutes.

I don't know if something is wrong with my browser or something else going.

Comment: Caching. The answer is always caching.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/